# What is the maximum a Pearson's chi square statistic can get?

Tags: probability-distributions

I actually know that the answer is $N(k-1)$  (where $k$ is the minimum between number of rows and number of columns).

However, I can not seem to find a simple proof for why the statistic is bounded by this.  Any suggestions (or references?)

Comment: Tal, can you state the problem in more details and add some motivation?

Comment: Sure.  The motivation is to understand Cramer's V statistic:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r's_V